# Fatal Error on Cart/Checkout

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having problems setting up WooCommerce on a child theme in Wordpress.

Everything appears to be fine, until you get to the cart and checkout pages, where I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function is_visible() on a non-object in /home/electric/public_html/test/creative/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-product.php on line 23

I've Googled, read tutorials and guides but nothing seems to fix it. Has anyone else experienced a similar problem, and can offer a solution?

I've uninstalled the plugin, deactivated/reactivated and changed templates. It works fine on the default twentyeleven theme, but since it's a child theme, I would have thought it would inherit the functions etc from the parent theme?

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding your permalinks.

Go to your dashboard, settings, permalinks, then change the permalink to ID, save, and then change it back to what you had.

Comment: I've just tried that, and unfortunately it didn't make a difference. Because it works in a different theme, is there something I'm missing in my custom theme? I'm just confused because since it's a child theme, there shouldn't be anything functionality-wise missing, right?

Comment: No, I'm not. Should I install it?

Comment: No, WPML is for translations. you tried this http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-woocommerce-excelling-ecommerce-fatal-error-when-going-to-cart-or-checkout ?

Comment: Yes - tried that. Works fine on the twentyeleven theme. I'm using that as a parent, which is why I'm unsure what's causing a problem - especially as the file name in question (/home/electric/public_html/test/creative/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-product.php) hasn't been touched!?

Comment: Maybe the theme/plugin is not compatible with your version of Wordpress.

Comment: It's the most up to date version of Wordpress and I've used this plugin on another installation, which works fine. That installation is also on 3.5.1. The theme itself is most likely the problem, but I'm unsure why as it is a child theme - there must be something I'm missing, which is why I've asked the question...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If you were trying to get products on your custom page, you need to change main shop page in woocommerce settings to your page.